# use multiple variables to create string

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have variables that I want to use to create a string that can be printed to a `UILabel`.

> maturityDate | ComparisonTerm | monthsToMaturity | ComparisonRate

The following are variables:

```
maturitDate:Date // value (value to return MMM DD, YYYY) Ex June 23, 2017

ComparisonTerm: Double
MonthsToMaturity: Double
ComparisonRate: Double
```

I want the "|" bars to be separators. My biggest challenge has been dealing with the date value. It currently returns `2021-09-01 04:00:00 + 000` as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty simple for the other three variable like this

```
   "\(ComparisonTerm) | \(monthsToMaturity) | \(ComparisonRate)"
```

For the date, you have to use a date formatter

```
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateStyle = .mediumStyle  // or .shortStyle
      dateFormatter.timeStyle = .noStyle
```

So the required date String is basically

```
    "\(dateFormatter.dateFromString(maturitDate)) | \(ComparisonTerm) | \(monthsToMaturity) | \(ComparisonRate) "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

let maturityDate = Date()
let maturityDateStr = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: maturityDate)

let comparisonTerm : Double = 0.1
let monthsToMaturity : Double = 0.2
let comparisonRate : Double = 0.3

let str = "\(maturityDateStr) | \(comparisonTerm) | \(monthsToMaturity) | \(comparisonRate)"
```